# Can not get the root domain request in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to get the request which is sent by going to http://localhost:4000 in my `server.js`:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log('This should be logged when I go to http://localhost:4000/')
});
```

But when I go to `http://localhost:4000` I don't get that console log?

Instead if I go to anything else than just a / it works:  `http://localhost:4000/ccc`

```
app.get("/ccc", (req, res) => {
        console.log('This is working')
});
```

What is wrong with Node.js? and How can I fix this?

Here is the full code of my server.js:

```
require('rootpath')();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const errorHandler = require('_middleware/error-handler');
const path = require('path');
const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');
const session = require('express-session');
const { authorize } = require('_middleware/authorize');
app.use(session({secret: 'mySecret', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.json());

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views/dashboard'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views/landing'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views/login'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname + '/views'));

// allow cors requests from any origin and with credentials
app.use(cors({ origin: (origin, callback) => callback(null, true), credentials: true }));

// accounts routes
app.use('/accounts', require('./accounts/accounts.controller'));

app.use('/google-login', require('_helpers/google-login'));

app.use('/mother', require('./mother/mother.controller'));

app.use('/api-docs', require('_helpers/swagger'));

// global error handler
app.use(errorHandler);


// Routes managment
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log('This is not reached')
    // res.redirect(`${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/accounts/dashboard`);
    // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/views/landing/index.html'));
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.render("login/index", { request: 'login' });
});

app.get("/signup", (req, res) => {
    res.render("login/index", { request: 'signup' });
});

// start server
const port = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? (process.env.PORT || 80) : 4000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on portsssss ' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The route order is important in some cases.

I think your route should come first.

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log('This is not reached')
    // res.redirect(`${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/accounts/dashboard`);
    // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/views/landing/index.html'));
});
// other routes under here
```